# Build grapesjs with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, grapesjs

I want to contribute to grapesjs. However, I am stupid about using webpack and babel. When I tried to build grapesjs, I am taking some errors.

Errors:

```
> grapesjs@0.16.22 build
> npm run check && npm run v:patch && npm run build-dev && npm run build-prod


> grapesjs@0.16.22 check
> npm run lint && npm run test


> grapesjs@0.16.22 lint
> eslint src

sh: 1: eslint: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /home/furkan/Desktop/grapesjs/grapesjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c eslint src

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/furkan/.npm/_logs/2020-12-19T09_25_34_660Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /home/furkan/Desktop/grapesjs/grapesjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run lint && npm run test

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/furkan/.npm/_logs/2020-12-19T09_25_34_831Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /home/furkan/Desktop/grapesjs/grapesjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run check && npm run v:patch && npm run build-dev && npm run build-prod

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/furkan/.npm/_logs/2020-12-19T09_25_34_931Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `npm install` before running build, to install the package's dependencies.